# Camel: Unresolved dependency exception for Camel Component

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

I am creating a Maven based Camel Component. I have added relevant dependencies in POM.xml but still I get below exception:

Unresolved dependency: (&(component=FileFormatConversion)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver))

I was able to build & run the Maven project. My component jar is however present in the component Folder:

[Component Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZBxC.jpg)

Can anyone advise if there is some issue with my POM or the reason behind this exception. Here is my POM.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>FileFormatConversion</groupId>
<artifactId>FileFormatConversion</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<name>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</name>

<properties>
    <camel.version>2.18.0</camel.version>
    <import.packages>*;version="0";resolution:=optional</import.packages>
    <private.packages>!*</private.packages>
    <symbolic.name>${project.groupId}</symbolic.name>
    <embed-dep>*;scope=compile;type=!pom;inline=true</embed-dep>
    <unpack-bundle>false</unpack-bundle>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Check for the latest version of this artifact in central maven repository -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.cloud.adk</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.sap.cloud.adk.build.archive</artifactId>
        <version>1.24.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-component -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-component</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/in.jlibs/jlibs-xsd -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>in.jlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jlibs-xsd</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>in.jlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jlibs-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>in.jlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jlibs-visitor</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>in.jlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jlibs-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache/xerces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
        <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>

            <configuration>
                <excludeDependencies>true</excludeDependencies>

                <instructions>
                    <Include-Resource>src/main/resources/,lib/</Include-Resource>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${symbolic.name}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Classpath>.,jax-qname.jar,jaxmexs-0.5.jar,xsd-2.2.3.jar,jlibs-core-2.2.1.jar,jlibs-visitor-2.2.1.jar,jlibs-xml-2.2.1.jar,
                        jlibs-xsd-2.2.1.jar,xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar,xml-apis-1.4.01.jar,FileFormatConversion-1.0.0.jar
                    </Bundle-Classpath>

                    <Import-Package>${import.packages}</Import-Package>

                </instructions>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>




        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>

                        <!-- Specify the artifacts to be excluded in the dependencies -->
                        <excludeArtifactIds></excludeArtifactIds>

                        <!-- Specify the group ids to be excluded in the dependencies -->
                        <excludeGroupIds>com.sap.cloud.adk,org.apache.camel,org.slf4j,log4j,in.jlibs,xerces,org.apache</excludeGroupIds>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.adk</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.sap.cloud.adk.build.archive</artifactId>
            <version>1.24.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.adk</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.sap.cloud.adk.build.archive</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-adapter</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <adapterProjectDirectory>${project.basedir}</adapterProjectDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue myself. The Problem was in below Statement:

${import.packages}

Answer (score 0):

What is this?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-component</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

That does not look correct as its some old stuff from Camel 1.x. You should remove that.

And you need to tell more how you run this? It seems like you use OSGi/Karaf or something. But take a look at how any of the existing components as an example to build custom components, or the Camel Maven archetype for component.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply but removing this line did not help. I am using OSGi. I still get the same error. I deploy the Code on SAP Cloud Environment where I get this error.

Comment: You need to ask SAP support for this, Apache Camel in general dont have a  _component_ folder where you drop JAR files into

Comment: Hi, I manually created a component Folder & added the jar. Refer to the screenshot posted in my original post. Still it did not help.